# How can we show $|\ln z-(z-1)|\le|z-1|^2$, for an arbitrary branch of $\ln$, for all $z\in\mathbb C$ with $|z-1|<\frac12$?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, taylor-expansion

Let $\operatorname{arg}_{\phi_0}z$ denote the argument of $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ in $(\phi_0,\phi+2\pi]$ and $$\ln_\varphi(z):=\ln|z|+{\rm i}\operatorname{arg}_{\phi_0}z$$ for $\phi_0\in(-2\pi,0]$. We know that $\ln_\varphi(z)$ is differentiable outside $$R_{\phi_0}:=\{0\}\cup\{z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}:\operatorname{arg}_{\phi_0}z=\phi_0\}$$ with derivative $\frac1z$.

> How can we use Taylor's theorem with Schlömlich's form of the remainder to show that $$\left|\ln_{\phi_0}z-(z-1)\right|\le|z-1|^2\tag1$$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$ with $|z-1|<\frac12$?

This is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2061977/47771) for the principal branch, i.e. $\phi_0=-\pi$, and using the integral form of the remainder in Taylor's theorem.

The basic idea should be to define $f(z):=\ln_{\phi_0}z-(z-1)$ on an appropriate set $U$ and define $g(t):=f(tz)$ for $t\in I$ for some $I$ with $Iz\subseteq U$. If $p>-1$ and $a,x\in I$ with $a<x$, then Taylor's theorem yields that there is a $c\in(a,x)$ with $$g(x)=g(a)+(x-a)g'(a)+\frac{(x-a)^{p+1}}{p+1}g''(c)(x-c)^{1-p}\tag1.$$

But how do we need to choose $U,I,a,x$ and how do we see the claim from $(1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|z-1|<1$ and
$$ \tag{$*$}
|\ln z-(z-1)|\le|z-1|^2
$$
for some branch of the logarithm then
$$
 |\arg z| = |\operatorname{Im}(\ln z)| \le |\ln(z)| \le |z-1| + |z-1|^2 < 2 < \pi \, .
$$
Therefore $(*)$ holds exactly for the principal value of the logarithm, and not for other values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can we find a generalization (depending on $\phi_0$) of $(1)$ which holds for an arbitrary branch?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: If $\ln(z)$ is not the principal value of the logarithm then you have to replace it by $\ln(z) - 2k\pi i$ with the proper $k$.